# Strange problem with Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I have recently installed Apache 1.3.41 on a Windows Vista machine. I have not changed the default settings in httpd.conf aprart from trying to setup virtual hosts, as follows:

Added some host names in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
#::1         localhost
127.0.0.1    mysite
127.0.0.1    mydomain
```

I made the following folders in C:/Users/Moukasp/

```
C:/Users/Moukasp/Apache
C:/Users/Moukasp/django/mysite
```

Then added some simple html pages in each of those folder and the `c:/Users/Moukasp/pictures` folder and, finally, I added the following settings at the end of httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost localhost>
# ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Moukasp/Apache"
ServerName localhost
Alias "/pics" "c:/users/moukasp/pictures" 
Alias "/ap"  "C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache/htdocs"
Alias "/dj" "C:/Users/Moukasp/django/mysite"  
# ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
# CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mysite> 
# ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Moukasp/django/mysite"
ServerName mysite
# ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
# CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mydomain>
# ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Moukasp/django/mysite"
ServerName mydomain
# ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
# CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

So, urls

```
http://localhost 
http://localhost/pics
http://localhost/ap
http://localhost/dj
http://mydomain
```

work fine. But I there's no response from `http://mysite` which, as can be seen from the settings, serves from the same folder as `http://mydomain`. I have tried various names but no response. The hosts file is being read every time I start the Apache server. I even removed the `mydomain` server from the hosts file and the `httpd.conf` lest there's a limitation in the number of virtual hosts, but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, els I go mad! It is true, I have being trying this after complete failure to make Apache work with mod_python for django! I just hoped that a step at a time would lead to some success!

Comment: What does "no response" mean?

Comment: What is "serverfault"?
"no response" means that the request "http://mysite/" results in a timeout.

Comment: serverfault.com is another site better suited to these questions

Comment: Since you're getting hits on "mydomain", which appears to be configured exactly like "mysite", it's probably not a config problem. And Apache has no problems (that I've seen) with dozens of hosts on the same IP. So time for standard debugging: have you checked the access log to verify that you're getting hits on "mysite"? Since it's Django, are your URL configs looking specifically for "mydomain"?

Comment: SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED! The problem was with the proxy server. I had set it to override 127.0.0.1 and mydomain (some time ago) but not mysite which I added very recently! Stupid me! Many thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

In your httpd.conf. My config file includes a comment stating a port-specifier should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The `VirtualHost` and `NameVirtualHost` directives should have IP addresses and ports:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> 
# ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Moukasp/django/mysite"
ServerName mysite
# ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
# CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80` but it **doesn't** make any difference! The only servers that work are `localhost` and `mydomain`. 
I wonder whether I need to do something more than just declare the server name of each virtual host in the `hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a port declaration to the hosts.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Moukasp/django/mysite"
ServerName mydomain
</VirtualHost>
```